# How can I detect single or double quotes in a string with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string like `test@gmail.com`, for which I want to detect that it does not contain single or double quotes. Why doesn't the following code work?

```
preg_match('[\'|\"]', $textData) ? true : false;
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's an error about delimiters (or regex compilation failing) you're missing as you've got display_errors off: `preg_match('/[\'"]/', $textData)`

Comment: The code works for me. What are you assigning to that ternary? https://3v4l.org/jpIen `false` because it doesn't contain a quote. You also don't need to escape the double quote.

Comment: @user3783243: it work for only single quotes, but it misses double quotes. My target is to detect the string contains single or double quotes. Please help

Comment: It works for double quotes the same as single quotes. https://3v4l.org/7GcXP Maybe you have smart quotes or some other none standard double quote. Please provide `$textData` that has the literal character you want to disallow.